# Remember The Milk client for Mac?

Tags: macos, rememberthemilk

Is there a free client for Remember the Milk for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a client, but you can try out [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) which allows you to make what they call site specific browsers. It's the next best thing to having a dedicated application.

See here for more: http://www.creativeapplications.net/2008/11/15/10-must-have-tools-for-rememberthemilk-on-the-desktop-webapp/

Answer (score 1):

Look under services on their web site, there is a widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iCal feeds and a Remember the Milk widget to manage your tasks on RTM with your Mac OS X. You can check out some of the other options available at the Remember the Milk Services page found here: http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/